# Availability Check from MySQL with PHP Jquery

Tags: php, session

I've a online book store where I sell books. Here I store data's of the cart on session. When two or more books are selected there may not be all the books available. I can do check only fore one book that is available or not. But I can't make it through when two or more books selected for ordering. What I did for one book is:

```
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM book_table WHERE id IN ($cart)");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $q=mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT available FROM book_table WHERE id='$row[0]'"));
    if($q!=0){
        //order goes fore processing.
    }
    else{
        //books not available.
        $q2=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT name FROM book_table WHERE id='$row[0]'"));
        echo "The book: $q2[0] Not Available";
        //If there is more than 1 books in the cart and one or two books of them are not in the stock, its showing the order cant be processed(But I want to show which books aren't available).
    }
}
```

Here $cart is the books cart saved on session like 1,2,3,4.
Now I need to show which books aren't available to buy by redirecting with another page.

Can anyone help me out on this?

Comment: So each physical book has its own row in the database?  Wouldn't it be easier to have a quantity on hand for a given title?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like below,

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT id,available FROM book_table WHERE id IN ($cart) ");
$books_available_num = mysql_num_rows($query);
$books_order_num = count(explode(",",$cart));//i think there should be better way to do this...
if($books_available_num==0){
    //no book is available
}elseif($books_available_num==$books_order_num ){
    //all books are available
    while($fetch=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        //order done successfully. 
    }

}else{
    //some are available some are not.
    while($fetch=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        if($fetch['status']=="available"){
             //place in order
        }else{
            //this is not available 
        }
    }
}
//rest of code. I think now you can do yourself.
```

I show you method and you can improve yourself. Code may contain errors, and you can improve it.

Answer (score 0):

make a array and put id and availaibilty as key and values pair and check for availaiblity for each id.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ajax like without redirecting to other page

```
$.ajax({
          url     :'yourpage.php',
          type    :'post',
          sucess  : function(data){ alert(data)}
       })
```

and your php code need a bit modification

```
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM book_table WHERE id IN ($cart)");
    $error  = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$q=mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT available FROM book_table WHERE id='$row[0]'"));
if($q!=0){
    //order goes fore processing.
}
else{
    //books not available.
    $q2=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT name FROM book_table WHERE id='$row[0]'"));
    $error[] = "The book: $q2[0] Not Available";
    //If there is more than 1 books in the cart and one or two books of them are not in the stock, its showing the order cant be processed(But I want to show which books aren't available).
}

  if (!empty(error))
  {
        // print array as you want
  }
  else
   {
       echo "order successfully placed"
   }
}
```

see more about [jquery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

if you want to do that redirecting to other page the out `$error` in session.
I dont think any other thing can help you

**NOTE**  : avoid using mysql_* as they are deprecated

Comment: 1 database query is enough. more than 1 query causes application slow. See my query below.

Comment: @web2students.com you are right .. but thats not the OP problem so I didnt cared about that

Comment: It's always good habit to save money, save RAM and hard disk of computer and save water. :P Just kidding... :)

Comment: Ajax code isn't working.

    $.ajax({
          url     :'yourpage.php',
          type    :'post',
          sucess  : function(data){ alert(data)}
       })

Comment: The page isn't completely loading after using this code. I've some other js code on that page and they aren't loading when using this code.

Comment: @MiraazFaiz when are you calling ajax.. you must associate some event with it

Comment: Can you please explain? I'm not familiar with it

Answer (score 0):

```
$all_available = true;
$orders = array();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, available, name FROM book_table WHERE id IN ($cart)");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  if ($row['available')) {
    $orders[] = $row['id'];
  } else {
    $all_available = false;
    echo "The book: " . $row['name'] . " is not available.\n"
  }
}
if ($all_available) {
  // Process $orders
} else {
  // Send redirect
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this one works for me but I need something like it will check automatically after 10-15secs by ajax whether its available now or not. Can it be possible?

Comment: You need to do that with AJAX in the client.

Comment: Can you please to do that for me?

Comment: It's outside the scope of this question, and isn't even an appropriate SO question. You write the code, and if you run into trouble post a new question.